# A link on top of an image link

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm building a landing page and I encounter a problem. I have an image of a project that when is clicked will zoom in a gallery mode and on top of that image it is a link towards the Behance page of the project. But what ever I do when I click the project link is opening still the image gallery. This is my code:

```html
<div class="row masonry-wrap">
  <div class="masonry">

    <div class="masonry__brick" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="item-folio">


        <div class="item-folio__thumb">

          <a href="images/portfolio/gallery/LiveStreaming.png" class="thumb-link" title="Live" data-size="1617x1440">
            <img src="images/portfolio/LiveStream500x625.jpg" srcset="images/portfolio/LiveStream500x625.jpg 1x, images/portfolio/LiveStream1000x1250.jpg 2x" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/77261419/Live-Streaming-Landing-Page-Design" class="item-folio__project-link" title="Project link">
                            Project Link
                        </a>

        <div class="item-folio__text">
          <h3 class="item-folio__title">
            Live Streaming Landing Page
          </h3>
          <p class="item-folio__cat">
            UI Design
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="item-folio__caption">
          <p>A modern touch to a simple service. UI design made in Sketch for a Live Streaming Landing Page.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- end item-folio -->
    </div>
    <!-- end masonry__brick -->

  </div>
  <!-- end masonry -->
</div>
<!-- end masonry-wrap -->
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: there's nothing obviously wrong with the html you've posted, it must be coming from css or javascript, we'll need to see those to help further.

Comment: I was putting the hole code on Codepen to share it here as requested but there was working. I really couldn't get it. So in the end I was putting an inline js in the link tag: onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false; And with this was working. Thank you @digital-pollution

Comment: indicates that probably there is another javascript event bubbling over to you link. If you're working with some third party gallery then your solution is a clean enough fix. :)